Would mixing different purple/blue dyes be the solution to the doubt around tekhelet dye sources?
The source of the animal used to produce the dye used for tekhelet is something of a mystery. While many modern scholars suggest it was one of multiple species of ocean mollusk, we don't truly know for certain what animal it was.
There have been a few groups in Israel and abroad who claim to have identified the creature used to produce the dye. Some groups even sell what they claim to be the "authentic" tzitzit using this dye. This hasn't caught on as the doubt around the source is too great of a hurdle for most Rabbis to endorse it.
Hence why the majority just wear white tzitzits.
This is where my hypothetical solution comes in.
The general consensus is that this creature is one of multiple types of sea mollusk. Typically referred to as a sea snail.
This narrows the choice down to maybe 3 or so shell bodied mollusks which produce a similar blue/purple dye. The problem we run into is "which one?"
If we know for certain it HAS to be at least one of these only creatures which fits the description, wouldn't the most appropriate solution be to mix the dyes of all 3 of these creatures together to produce a dye which is as close to the original as realistically possible?
Think about it. If you produce a dye which is 3 equal parts of the 3 most likely candidates for the dye, you would be 100% guaranteed to be using the correct dye even if it is partially adulterated with a cousin species of similar property.
The final product would be a dye which in all likelihood is the correct source. It would also be produced in a way which recognizes human error and attempts to circumvent that human error by compiling the best options into a single answer.
I'm reminded of the minhag of wearing multiple types of tefillin.
Rashi and Rabbeinu Tam contradicted one another on what order Sh'ma and V'haya im shamoa should be in the boxes. This resulted in a custom of some jews wearing two different pairs of tefillin in either order.
Would this solution not echo this situation in certain regards? Obviously, Jews who cover their bases are highly respected and deemed pious in the eyes of hashem. Could this solution not also be considered valid given that tradition?

If you take the tefillin precedent all the way, why not wear three sets of tzitzit, each dyed with a different techelet version?

Your claim that it is one of the three candidates is the problem. The by far majority opinion among poskim is that we do not have any viable candidates for techeiles.

The reasons for wearing Rabbeinu Tam tefillin are kabbalistic, not to be yotzei l'chol hadei'os. To quote the Gra, if that's your objective you need to be wearing 64 pairs of tefillin, not two.
